# Creating a http address for kml

Tags: api, http, kml

I'm currently using a websites' API(not google) to create an application. What I'm wondering is that how do I create a http address for my kml? for example; http://www.onemap.sg/uploadedcsvkml/sample.kml

Is there any way for me to create a similar link like the above so that I can use the link to overlay the kml file onto the map?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what the URL looks like (as long as it is [valid as a URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)). You just need to ensure that when you serve it up over HTTP, [you supply the correct mimetype](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/faq.html#mimetypes). How you go about that depends on your webserver and whether you are serving up static files or generating them on demand using a scripting language.

Since you've provided no details of the webserver nor any scripting language, we can't tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same for my App using Onemap: all you need to do is upload the kml file to a webserver and just put down

www.YourWebsite.com/YourFileName.kml

as your link